# yii cgridview Property "CActiveDataProvider.abc" is not defined

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider, cgridview

In my controller:

```
$model = new Sheets();
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->compare('id', $model->id);
            $criteria->compare('track_name', $model->track_name, true);
            $criteria->addCondition('user_id = '.Yii::app()->user->getId().' and '.$listSetups[$i]['condition']);

$setups = new CActiveDataProvider($model, array('criteria' => $criteria));
```

In my view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'sheets-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $model,
        //'filter' => $model,
        'template'=>'{items}<div class="nav-controller">{pager}</div>',
            'enableSorting' => false,
            'columns' => array(

            array(
                  'header' => 'Track',
                  'name' => 'track_name',
                  'value' => $model->track_name,
                  'htmlOptions' => array(
                  'width' => '135px',
                 ),
            ),
```

But I get this error:

> Error:Property "CActiveDataProvider.track_name" is not defined.

Anybody can show me why is this? And how can i fix it.And I don't want to use `$data->track_name` because I want to use $model->track_name in this code to customize button 'Add' :

```
array(
        'header' => '',
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template' => '<div class="wrapper-tools">{share}{facebook}{twitter}{download}{add}{update}{delete2}</div>',
        'buttons'=>array (                                
                            'add' => array
                             (
                                 'label'=>'Add favorite',
                                 'imageUrl'=> (Users::model()->checkFavorite(Yii::app()->user->getId(), $model->track_name)) ? Yii::app()->themeManager->baseUrl."/default/images/favorite.png" : Yii::app()->themeManager->baseUrl."/default/images/favorite-disabled.png",
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/sheets/", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                                    'options' => array('id' => 'add-favorite', 'class' => 'admin-tools' ),
                                    //'visible' => 'Users::model()->checkFavorite(Yii::app()->user->getId(), $data->id) == false',
                                ),

                        ),
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'class' => 'admin-tools-2',
                        ),
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CGridView you have to use `$data->track_name`, the following line is wrong:

```
'value' => $model->track_name,
```

You need to set the value like so:

```
'value' => '$data->track_name',
```

**UPDATE**

As you mention you want to use the data in a button for each line you still need to use the data param, as the CGridView widget renders one line at a time with the given line's data in the `$data` param, `$model->attribute` still has no context here as it will be different for every line in the CGridView.

Because `imageUrl` param isn't evaluated, you can't use the `$data` param in there by default, but you can if you create a custom class to extend CButtonColumn and override this behaviour.

You could create a class, say `MyCButtonColumn`, and save it in your `components` folder in a file named `MyCButtonColumn.php` (this way it will be auto loaded when needed).

Now you'll need to create a `renderButton` method within this new class to evaluate `imageUrl` if it needs evaluating and then return the result of the standard `CButtonColumn::renderButton()` method with the newly evaluated `imageUrl` like so:

```
class MyCButtonColumn extends CButtonColumn
{
    protected function renderButton($id,$button,$row,$data)
    {
        if(isset($button['imageUrl']) && is_string($button['imageUrl']) && strpos($button['imageUrl'],'$data')!==false)
            $button['imageUrl'] = $this->evaluateExpression($button['imageUrl'],array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));

        return parent::renderButton($id,$button,$row,$data);
    }
}
```

Lastly you'll need to change the class of your button column from `CButtonColumn` to `MyCButtonColumn`. Once you've done that then you will be able to parse `$data` variables through the `imageUrl` variable like so:

```
array(
    ...
    'class' => 'MyCButtonColumn',
    ...
    'buttons'=>array (
        'add' => array(
            ...
            'imageUrl'=> '(Users::model()->checkFavorite(Yii::app()->user->getId(),$data->track_name)) ? Yii::app()->themeManager->baseUrl."/default/images/favorite.png" : Yii::app()->themeManager->baseUrl."/default/images/favorite-disabled.png"',
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
),
```

Comment: for what reason? You *have* to use $data in the value field of CGridView columns, $model->track_name has no value

Comment: I updated my question to add reason...
I can't use '$data->track_name' in this situation.

Comment: ah ok, well the `imageUrl` param is a different case, as you've found out I guess. I've added an update to my answer for you.

Comment: You should never advice to modify a core class, if you need to modify anything, subclass, but never edit the framework's files!

Comment: @Asgaroth, thanks for the input, I've updated the answer taking aboard your feedback, feel free to chip in!